# Why ViewState changes

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, state-management

I have a ViewState["blah"] that is a list of strings. At some point I set a List<string> variable to be equal to view state. Whatever change I make to this variable affects the view state:

```
List<string> a = {"1", "2", "3"};
ViewState["Blah"] = a;
....
List<string> b = (List<string>)ViewState["Blah"];
b.Remove("2");
```

Now, ViewState["Blah"] is {"1", "3"}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where you are storing view state in which event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you do

```
List<string> b = (List<string>)ViewState["Blah"];
```

You're assigning to `b` a pointer to a place in memory (a reference) and not a copy of the list. This means that `b` and `ViewState["Blah"]` points to the same list and changes on either of those affect the other.

You could clone your list if you want to detach `b` from your `ViewState` instance

Comment: Claudio, how do I "clone" the list so that changes to it won't affect ViewState (using example code in my question)? I am guessing there is a better way than declare a new list, "c", and copy items from "b" to it.

Comment: I used List<string> c = new List<string>(b); is this the correct way of "cloning"?

Comment: @NoBullMan: that should do the trick for primitive types as string